# INSERT IF COUNT()=0

Tags: mysql, insert

The following MySQL syntax works correctly:

```
SELECT 
  IF (
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM preorder) = 0,
    1,
    (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM preorder)
  ) AS X
```

This gives me one value, which I want to insert into table preorder. If I try

```
INSERT INTO preorder (id) 
VALUES
  (SELECT 
    IF (
      (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM preorder) = 0,
      1,
      (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM preorder)
    ) AS X)
```

it doesn't work anymore. MySQL just tells me to read the menual :-)

The purpose of the syntax is to be able to create my own auto-incremental field. I want to insert 1 if the count is zero and the maximum value of the id column if the count is not zero.

Edit:
I managed to make it work with the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO preorder (id) 
VALUES
  (
    IF (
      (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM preorder AS Y) = 0,
      1,
      (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM preorder AS X)
    )
  )
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want your own auto-incremented field? What's wrong with the existing? Also, if you delete a row with your scheme, the next time you insert anything, you will get a duplicate.

Comment: Is there a better way for what? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you're just trying to number the rows, don't reinvent the `AUTO_INCREMENT`. What is the end goal here?

Comment: Kristian, I want a little more flexibility because the table I'm using will be used to store temporary data most of which will appear redundant a few minutes later.
Naltharial, I'm just trying to figure out how to get more flexibility regarding my ID numbers. I realise that this approach may not be exactly right.
For now, I'm just looking for any better alternative syntax that does exactly the same as I posted here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You can't `INSERT` into a table you use for a `SELECT` in a subquery.

Second: Even if it would sytnactically work, it wouldn't work functionalitywise: You have an enormous race condition, if 2 such queries go parallel

Third: MySQLs `AUTO_INCREMENT` does exactly that - have you looked into it?

Comment: Thanks, Eugen. The syntax works for me. I realise that concurrent queries might cause problems. I'm still thinking about this.
I know about AUTO_INCREMENT. Somehow this doesn't always work on all servers I am developing for (probably too old a version of MySQL or other software). It might use this later after I figure out a few other things.